# ColdFusion: No data was received in the uploaded file

Tags: file-upload, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

My error report told me that an error has occurred when an user tried uploading an empty file to my server (don't ask why the user did that - I don't know) and now I want to catch that exception which said "*No data was received in the uploaded file*". I wonder if there is a better way than putting a `<CFTRY>` around the `<CFFILE action="upload">` like this:

```
<CFTRY>
  <CFFILE action="upload" destination="#expandpath("upload")#" filefield="form.file" nameconflict="makeunique" />
  <CFCATCH>
    <!--- handle that error --->
  </CFCATCH>
</CFTRY>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try/Catch is the way I usually handle it.

```
<cftry>
    <cffile action="upload" ...>

    <cfcatch type="any">
        <cfif Find("Saving empty (zero-length) files is prohibited", CFCatch.Detail) GT 0>

            <!--- Create a zero length file on disk and continue processing as usual --->
            <cffile action="write" file="..." output="">
        <cfelse>
            <cfrethrow>
        </cfif>
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```