# 'No data was received in the uploaded file', but file is not empty

Tags: html, coldfusion

I'm trying to update a file sized 52KB, but I receive the following error:

```
No data was received in the uploaded file
Saving empty (zero-length) files is prohibited. 
Verify that you specified the correct file.
```

Here is a piece of my form:

```
<form method="post" 
    name="frm_testcase"action="index.cfm?fuseaction=tables.testcases" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="inputFile" type="file" size="50">
</form>
```

And here I try to upload the file:

```
<cffile action = "upload" 
    fileField = "form.inputFile" 
    destination = "#local#" 
    <!---accept = "text/html" --->
    nameConflict = "MakeUnique"
    result = "upInputFile">
```

I tried to upload many different files, but I always get the same error message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ColdFusion: No data was received in the uploaded file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249065/coldfusion-no-data-was-received-in-the-uploaded-file)

Comment: And what are the contents of the file you are uploading?

Comment: Also, is there any redirection involved ie framework? (BTW: You might chose a different variable name than `local`, since it is [the name of a system scope in CF9+](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09af4-7ff1.html))

Comment: It's not a duplicated post. The post you mentioned is to handle the error when someone tries to upload an empty file. In my case, I'm not uploading an empty file.

Comment: The contents are various: I TRIED XLS, DOC, JPG, any file triggers this error message.

Comment: Leigt, I replaced "local" by "pasta" but it didn't solve.

Comment: (Edit) @MarcelaRocha - Dump the `FORM` scope just *before* your cffile code. What fields does it contain? Re: *I replaced "local" by "pasta"* It was not supposed to solve the problem :) That was just a general comment about avoiding additional problems by not using reserved words like `local`.

Comment: Also...try this with a self posting test page outside of FuseBox to eliminate that as a potential source for the issue (though, I doubt it is)

Comment: @PWKad - Actually this is a different question. The other thread is about how handle the error when the file *is* empty. This thread is asking why the error is occurring when the file is *not* empty.

Comment: Generally such an error might also occur if the POST is converted into a GET request because the browser is redirected from the initial URL.

Comment: Could be a permissions issue...possibly with the ColdFusion temp directory (that is where files get uploaded when form submitted - before `cffile` is called.

Comment: I'm sorry guys! It was my lack of attention, I had two fields in my form with the same name inputFile, so I changed the name of the second one to the correct name, and it's working now! Thank you very much for the support!

Comment: @MarcelaRocha - Ah, interesting how the problem manifested itself. I noticed it only occurs if one of the file fields is blank. If they are both populated, the error goes away, but of course there is no way to access the second file. You should write that up as a "answer", so it is more visible.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<cffile action = "upload" 
fileField = "inputFile" 
destination = "#local#" 
<!---accept = "text/html" --->
nameConflict = "MakeUnique"
result = "upInputFile">
```

ColdFusion is likely looking for a form field named `form.inputFile` - which does not exist -  instead of a form field named `inputfile` - which does exist.

Comment: The `inputFile` form field does exist, but you are correct that the `cffile` attribute `fileField` does not expect the form prefix. Per the example [found here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-738f.html).

Comment: The form field named  `inputFile` may exist, but the form field named `form.inputField` does not - which is what ColdFusion would be looking for based on his sample code.

Comment: Correct. That's what I was trying to point out in my comment. The `form.` prefix is not needed in this case. I was confused by this as well (hence my previous answer that you clarified for me). So I was just trying to comment here since you normally do prefix form fields with `form.` in ColdFusion.  Hopefully that is not too confusing.

Comment: I never thought it was confusing..until I just now tried to explain it.

Comment: Ha! I'm confused now too. But I think your answer is correct. Kudos!

Comment: Hm.. I do not think that is the issue. CF should accept it either way: `fileField = "inputFile"` OR `fileField = "form.inputFile"`.

Comment: Hrm.....so, yea, @Leigh is correct it works with `form.inputFile`. Sorry. I wonder now...could it be a permissions issue with the ColdFusion temp directory or the directory to which you are trying to upload the file(s).

Answer (score 0):

I had two fields in my form with the same name inputFile, so I changed the name of the second one to the correct name, and it's working now!